# How do I get the address of elements in a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, memory-address

I have a `char` array and I need to get the address of each element.

```
cout << &charArray
```

gives me a valid address, However if I try to get the address of a specific element, it spits out garbage:

```
cout << &charArray[0]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
std::cout << (void*) &charArray[0];
```

There's an overload of `operator<<` for `char*`, that tries to print the nul-terminated string that it thinks your pointer points to the first character of. But not all char arrays are nul-terminated strings, hence the garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
&charArray + index * sizeof(char)
```